# How to sum cluster data?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, clustering, multivariate-analysis

I have a binary variable with probit model, i.e., $P(Y_{ij}=1|X_j)= \Phi(a_i+b_iX_j)$, where $X_j$ is $\mathcal N(0,1)$, and $a_i$ and $b_i$ are regression parameters.

I am wondering what the expected value of $Y_j=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{ij}$ is. Is there a known distribution for $Y_j$?

Comment: Switch to logit, then the sum of predicted probabilities is equal to the sum of outcomes. For probit, it should be close, but for logit, it is identical. Economists tend to like probit models, probably because they like the normal error terms; the rest of the applied statistics world likes logit models because of the sufficient statistics, the above summing property, and ease of the log-odds ratio interpretation.

Comment: How can I prove the sum of predicted probabilities is equal to the sum of outcomes for logit function and how much is the contribution of $\sum a_i$ and $\sum b_i$ in $\sum Y_i$? Is there any referrence?

Comment: @Tommy Please register your account.

Comment: I guess it should follow somehow from the score equations. This is so engraved in my head that I can't really give a reference, off the top of it. I don't think the result will hold for the clustered data though, since you are intergrating out the random effects, and by Jensen's inequality must be screwing things up. I don't quite understand what the "contributions" of $a_i$ and $b_i$ are.